# Tkinter next button best practise?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, button, counter

I'm trying to navigate through a list[] of items via "Next" and "previous" buttons in Python Tkinter.

For now, I have created a workaround using a "Button click counter" I found from
[this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904351/10697107)

I have some experience with Python but am building my first ever GUI.

**Here is my current working solution:**

Declaring a button counter outside as a global:

```
counter = 0 # My global counter set outside of all functions

class App(customtkinter.CTk):  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Creating the buttons:

```
self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame,text="Previous", command=self.sidebar_button_event_previous)
self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame,text="Next", command=self.sidebar_button_event_next)
self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
```

What a button click responds to:

```
def sidebar_button_event_next(self):
    global counter
    counter = counter +1 # Increase counter by 1 on button click
    print(f"{Linegenerator(counter)}") # Linegenerator is where my populated list, which returns the matching item according to "counter" increase/decrease
def sidebar_button_event_previous(self):
    global counter
    counter = counter -1 # Decrease counter by 1 on button click
    print(f"{Linegenerator(counter)}")
```

I feel like this is very hacky and there might be a more elegant solution to my current setup !?

As always, any ideas and hints are appreciated :)

Comment: Since you have used class, it is better to use class/instance variable instead of global variable.

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with a similar problem before, and I handled it something like this (modified to match your code)

I've tweaked things a bit so you only need to define one function that handles both "previous" and "next" steps. You'll need some way to keep track of the last used index that was passed to `Linegenerator`, so I've called that `self.last_generated_line_index` (to be overly descriptive).

I assume `Linegenerator` is indexing into a list somewhere, so that's how I've structured this answer.

You may want to tweak how this is done to better fit your needs, but I don't know offhand what `Linegenerator` is doing, so I went with this approach!

```
class App(customtkinter.CTk):  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.last_generated_line_index = 0  # start at 0
        # you'll want the selected index to 'wrap around' at the ends of the list
        # I have no idea how big your list is or what 'Linegenerator' will accept,
        # so I'm making these numbers up!!
        self.min_index = 0
        self.max_index = 12

        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(
            self.sidebar_frame,
            text="Previous",
            command=lambda: (self.sidebar_button_event(step=-1)
        )
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(
            self.sidebar_frame,
            text="Next",
            command=lambda: self.sidebar_button_event(step=1)
        )
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

    def sidebar_button_event(self, step: int):
        index = self.last_generated_line_index + step

        # wrap around the ends of the list
        if index > self.max_index:
            index = self.min_index
        elif index < self.min_index:
            index = self.max_index

        print(f'{Linegenerator(index)})
```